# how to get new action command in a while loop

Tags: java, events, while-loop, actionlistener

I make a program that adds a number to a JLabel when you click a button. I have 4 different buttons.

The problem is that I made a while loop and every time I click a button it  always adds the same number

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JLabel counter;
    private JButton val5;
    private JButton val10;
    private JButton val25;
    private JButton val50;

    public GUI() {
        super("The Title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        counter = new JLabel("This is the counter: 0");
        val5 = new JButton("5");
        val5.setActionCommand("5");
        val10 = new JButton("10");
        val10.setActionCommand("10");
        val25 = new JButton("25");
        val25.setActionCommand("25");
        val50 = new JButton("50");
        val50.setActionCommand("50");
        add(counter);
        add(val5);
        add(val10);
        add(val25);
        add(val50);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        val5.addActionListener(handler);
        val10.addActionListener(handler);
        val25.addActionListener(handler);
        val50.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
        int sum = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            while (sum < 1000) {
                String action = event.getActionCommand();
                int numberInt = Integer.parseInt(action);

                switch (numberInt) {
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("add 5");
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        System.out.println("add 10");
                        break;
                    case 25:
                        System.out.println("add 25");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("add 50");
                        break;
                    //counter.setText(String.valueOf(action));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please for the sake of everyone reading your code do not just throw the entire case statement on a single line.  That will only look worse with more code too.

Comment: You never update `sum`, so why do you expect your while-loop to terminate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code. Please don't just use it as solution but to show you where your current problem is.

```
private JLabel counter;
private JButton val5;
private JButton val10;
private JButton val25;
private JButton val50;

// a JLabel can only hold Strings, so you loose the int value. Therefore 
// you could hold the value in a separate variable and just update the label
// when you have a new value.
private int sum;   

public GUI() {
    super("The Title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    sum=0;                         // first we start at 0

    counter = new JLabel("This is the counter: 0");
    val5 = new JButton("5");
    val5.setActionCommand("5");
    val10 = new JButton("10");
    val10.setActionCommand("10");
    val25 = new JButton("25");
    val25.setActionCommand("25");
    val50 = new JButton("50");
    val50.setActionCommand("50");
    add(counter);
    add(val5);
    add(val10);
    add(val25);
    add(val50);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    val5.addActionListener(handler);
    val10.addActionListener(handler);
    val25.addActionListener(handler);
    val50.addActionListener(handler);
}


class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {      
    // you may even hold the sum variable here, but this class is supposed to be a listener, not a model for your view. 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if (GUI.this.sum < 1000) {    // your previous while loop was infinite. 
        // I don't know if you wanted to count to 1000 once the user clicks a button or just add the number. Anyway. 
        // GUI.this.sum will access the sum variable in the current GUI instance and then we check if the sum is smaller 1000. If so, we add the input value
            String action = event.getActionCommand();
            int numberInt = Integer.parseInt(action);
            // the switch is actually not necessary unless you plan to do more with it
            switch (numberInt) {
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("add 5");
                    break;
                case 10:
                    System.out.println("add 10");
                    break;
                case 25:
                    System.out.println("add 25");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("add 50");
                    break;
                //counter.setText(String.valueOf(action));
            }
            sum+=numberInt; // first we add the value from the button to the global sum
            counter.setText("This is the counter: "+sum); //then we update the text from the label with the new value
        }
    }
}
```

The example works, but it is not very clean. Reusing the same ActionListener is a noble approach, but casting the action command to get the value is a bit quirky.

Instead of the `setActionCommand("5");` and the full `ActionListener` implementation you could do this:

```
val5.addActionListener((e) -> {    // this is the lambda-approach to write the ActionListener implementation (since the interface has only one method, you can just write your method here)
     if(sum<1000){      // here you can access the sum variable directly
         sum+=5;        // update its value
         counter.setText(".....");  // set the new label text
     }
});
```

Although you have to do this for every button, it's more maintainable that way.

An even cleaner approach would be to write the calculating code in a separate method like this:

```
private void add(int number) {
    if (sum < 1000) {
        sum += number;
        counter.setText(".....");
    }
}
```

and then register the actionlistener to the buttons like this:

```
val5.addActionListener((e) -> add(5));   //for val10 you call add(10) and so on...
```